# Where can I buy poster-size reprints of great photographs?

Tags: photo-galleries, galleries

Please, correct me if this is off-topic question here.

I have recently found a great photograph of Beth Moon.

I would like to hang a poster-size reprint of this photo on my wall. I inquired a few galleries and prices they offered to me are way too much for my budget: ranging from 2400 euro for 17x22'' to 8500 euro for 20x30'' reprint. I guess this is because the author works in expensive platinum/palladium photographic medium and it her photographs are the result of 14 years work.

I was thinking about few possible solutions:

- Get a lower quality reprint for lower price. Can galleries do such reprints?
- Find another photography of a tree. Where do you find and buy such photographs? Both online and in real world? What prices I should prepare for?
- Take a similar photograph myself...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book measures 11x11 inches and is not that expensive. http://www.rakuten.com/prod/ancient-trees/261929890.html?listingId=-1&sclid=pla_google_rakuten.com&adid=29963&gclid=Cj0KEQjwyoCrBRCl-aa97pKX_t8BEiQAbrs_9LTHG12UhuDH6PIOaO94KnBMgeBzJPLRcT_gIlivKFcaAtuS8P8HAQ

I don't see any posters available. I searched framedart dotcom, allposters dotcom, posters dotcom, and art dotcom.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the book and it's really great, but I cannot hang it on a wall :-) Though I can extrapolate photos from the book to the poster size and see how they look like.

Comment: I know its smaller than what you want, but you can buy a second book, cut out a full page image, and have it framed. I've seen people decorate a room on a budget this way. You can often find inexpensive frames, provided the sizes match up.

Comment: Great idea. Thank you also for listing places with posters online. That's very inspiring and I'm thinking about finding a poster with another tree!